# Solution Verification for RMO (Indian Math Competition)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

> *Let N be the set of all positive integers and **$S={(a,b,c,d)\in N^4: a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2}$**. Find the largest positive integer m such that m
> divides abcd for all (a,b,c,d) \in S (RMO Problem 1: 29 Oct, 2023)*

For $a=b=2,c=1,d=3$:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=2^2+2^2+1^2=9=3^2=d^2\Rightarrow abcd=12\Rightarrow m\leq12$$

**abcd is divisible by 3 (working mod 3)**
If $a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2$ are not divisible by 3, then each can only be  1  (a perfect square can only be 0 or 1)
$$RHS=d^2\equiv1, LHS=a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv1+1+1\equiv3\equiv0\Rightarrow contradiction$$

**abcd is divisible by 4 (working mod 4)**
If $a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2$ are not divisible by 4, then each can only be 1 (a perfect square can only be 0 or 1)
$$RHS=d^2\equiv1, LHS=a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv1+1+1\equiv3\equiv0\Rightarrow contradiction$$

Since abcd is divisible by 3 and also by 4, it is divisible by $LCM(3,4)=12$.Hence:
$$m\geq12$$

Combine $m\leq12$ and $m\geq12$ to get
$$m=12$$

Comment: I am not sure why you think this is wrong. +1 for the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: When considering the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ modulo $4$, you use the fact that squares are congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4: every even number squares to be 0 modulo 4, and every odd number squares to be congruent to 1 modulo 4.

Showing $a^2,b^2,c^2$ and $d^2$ cannot all be 1 mod 4 thus only shows one of $a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2$ is divisible by $4$, or equivalently one of $a,b,c,d$ is even (*i.e.* divisible by $2$).

You need to argue that at least two of $a,b,c,d$ must be even. This just requires refining the analysis you have already done though!

Comment: I show by contradiction that a,b,c,d cannot all be 1 mod 4. Hence, at least one of them is 0 mod 4. Does that not show that the number is divisible by 4?

Comment: @Starlight You have shown that for at least one of $a,b,c,d$ its square is equivalent to $0$ modulo $4.$  That is not the same as proving that the number is divisible by $4.$

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully be a bit clearer about the gap in your proof. You are very close to a complete proof though!

Comment: I understood the mistake. I had the square mod 4 mixed up with the number mod 4. This was precisely the point I thought might have had a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the refinement of the mod 4 analysis (as suggested by krm2233).

We work with cases mod 4.
Case I: $d^2\equiv0(mod 4)$
Then $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv c^2\equiv0 (mod 4)$

Case II: $d^2\equiv1(mod 4)$
Then any two of a,b,c must be 0, and the third must be 1.

In both cases, we have two numbers whose squares are 0 mod 4,and hence the numbers themselves are 0 mod 2.

Hence, the numbers are even. Hence, abcd is divisible by 4.